# Hibernate Query on Entity Class

Tags: hibernate

I'm working with `Person.java.`

This Hibernate Entity does not have any fields marked `@Field.`

Another class, `Group.java` is an Entity that has fields marked `@Field`.

```
@Field
private int id;
```

In this legacy code, I see queries for Group:

```
   getEntityManager().createQuery("delete from group g where g.id = 
:inputId").setParameter("inputId", givenId).getSingleResult();
```

However, I'm not sure how to make a Hibernate query for an Entity that has no fields.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: does Person entity have any fields with @id ?

Comment: I was just being dumb. It turns out my Person had a field of type 'x.' I then made my query with "delete from person p where p.x.id = ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Field` is not a JPA annotation, and is not a Hibernate annotatiion either. I don't know from which package it comes from, but it doesn't have anything to do with JPA/Hibernate persistence. So, regarding Hibernate queries, the fact that a field has this annotation or not is irrelevant.

By default, without any annotation, all the fields of a JPA entity are persistent.